# Rigorous graph theory

Tags: graph-theory

In the textbook my university uses for a discrete mathematics course, planar graph's are defined to be those graphs which admit a representation in the plane whose edges only meet in common vertices, and such a representation is said to be a plane graph. Then it's said that a plane graph divides the plane in various regions, called faces. The book also says that any of these regions is bounded by a closed walk in the graph, and the degree of a face is defined to be the length of the walk that bounds it. All of this is obvious in the graph that the book provides as an example, but no proof is supplied for these statements.

To prove that the sum of the degrees of all faces is double the number of edges, it is argued that each edge is either in the boundary of two different regions, or it is visited twice in some of the boundary walks. No proof is supplied for this statement either.

Up until the section about planar graphs the book was quite rigorous, but I am not comfortable with these definitions and proofs. My question is, how can all of this be stated and proved in a more rigorous way, without having to resort to geometrical intuiton? I feel like topology is needed to treat this in a completely rigorous way, am I right?

Comment: As a first step toward a rigorous treatment, I'd be inclined to define planarity by requiring the edges to be piecewise linear arcs in the plane, rather than general topological arcs.  That probably won't avoid all topological considerations, but it should make them more tolerable.

Comment: Thanks! I have looked at a couple of other graph theory resources online and they all seem to share some lack of rigour. I suppose that a rigorous treatment of planar graphs is not very standard, right?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're right—a rigorous approach needs topology, specifically the Jordan Curve Theorem. I would suggest Diestel's [Graph Theory](http://www.flooved.com/reader/3447?no-redirect#102), Chapter 4, available online. It's not totally complete, but he at least gives an outline of the information you're looking for. I don't have my copy in front of me, but I'm fairly sure Mohar & Thomassen's [Graphs on Surfaces](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0801866898) is very thorough on the subject, if you're interested in more.

Comment: Thank you very much, exactly what I wanted.